# Can't drive the turtle in turtlesim

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just started working with ROS and I'm working through the beginner's tutorial. I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I'm at "Understanding ROS Topics"1.1.2 and when I implement rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key the turtle won't move around with my arrow keys.  Is there anything I need to do to set my keys so they will run the turtle?

Thanks, Gene

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12422/can%27t-drive-the-turtle-in-turtlesim/) by [GenePSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1562/genepsmith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
The terminal which has

```
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
```

running should be the active window on the desktop for it to drive the robot. I think this is what is missed.
If not you have to post the changes if any that you made or any error that you are getting.

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the answers.  It turns out, as I discovered about 15 minutes after I posted the request that I kept making the turtle terminal the active window and not the "turtle_teleop_key" terminal window.  When I made the "turtle_teleop_key" terminal active everything worked fine.

---

Originally posted by [GenePSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1562/genepsmith/) with karma: 61 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4